# Check whether the values of hashes are either both blank or both have a value

Tags: ruby, hash

I have two hashes of the same length:

```
hash1 = {"1"=>"val", "2"=>"val", "3"=>"", "4"=>""} 
hash2 = {"1"=>[""], "2"=>["value"], "3"=>["val1", "val2"], "4"=>[""]}
```

I need to compare them. The corresponding keys need to either both have a value (for `hash1`, this means non-blank, and for `hash2`, this means there must be a non-blank value in the array) or both have a blank value (for `hash2`, this means the value is [""]).

- Key `"1"` fails (array has one value and that value is blank)
- Key `"2"` passes (both have values)
- Key `"3"` fails (`hash1` is blank)
- Key `"4"` passes (`hash1` is blank and `hash2` has one value in the array and that value is blank)

If one of these comparisons fails, then I should get `false` returned. I'm not sure how to do a comparison like this.

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "`hash2` having one value and that one value is blank".

Comment: Perhaps you mean something else by "(need to either) both have a value (...)". When that condition is satisfied, then the other condition is always satisfied.

Comment: @sawa I updated it. Hopefully it is a bit more clear as to why it passes.

Comment: Do the hashes always have integer keys in the range of 1 to hash length? Are the values always strings in hash1 and arrays containing strings in hash2?

Comment: @Damon yes that is correct

Comment: @sawa `hash2` is always going to contain an array as a value, the array wont ever be empty but will contain an empty string, that is equlivent to an empty value in `hash1`. key 4 could have an empty string in the array as the first value and the second value in the array be another string (non empty), so thats why I said one value in the array and that value is an empty string

Comment: What if `hash1 = { "1"=>"" }` and `hash2 = { "1"=>["", ""] }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that hashes are already ordered:

```
hash1 = {"1"=>"val", "2"=>"val", "3"=>"", "4"=>""} 
hash2 = {"1"=>[""], "2"=>["value"], "3"=>["val1", "val2"], "4"=>[""]} 

hash1.zip(hash2).all? do |(_, fv), (_, lv)| 
  fv.empty? ^ !lv.all?(&:empty?)
end
```

Here we take a benefit of using `XOR`. Whether hashes are not ordered, the preprocessing (ordering) required.

According to @sawa’s and @CarySwoveland’s comments, for not sorted hashes:

```
hash1.sort.zip(hash2.sort).all? do |(fk, fv), (lk, lv)| 
  #   ⇓ consistency        ⇓ true if one operand is truthy, other is falsey
  (fk == lk) && (fv.empty? ^ !lv.all?(&:empty?))
end
```

Comment: With a bit more elaboration on the block variable profile, you can get rid of `map`, `first`, and `last`.

Comment: @sawa indeed, thank you. After all (read: with your advise) it appears to become a nifty solution.

Comment: We seem to have been thinking along the same lines. You are depending on the keys being in the same order in both hashes.

Comment: @CarySwoveland That's the OP's fault. If the OP meant the orders are not guaranteed, then the OP should have shown an example with random order. It is misleading. At the same time, the OP never wrote the orders are guaranteed, so your interpretation is also reasonable.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Indeed. After all. I dropped a comment about ordering in the answer.

Comment: Your interpretation was right the orders are guaranteed

Comment: @mudasobwa I need to skip the check on the first key for the hashes, (`hash1` will always have a value in it and `hash2` will be an empty array which is allowed for the first keys, but the rest need to be checked) what needs to be added to skip the first key in `unless head.zip(content).all? { |(_, fv), (_, lv)|  fv.empty? ^ !lv.all?(&:empty?) }`? or do you want me to open a new question

Comment: @mudasobwa I asked it here if your interested http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35762523/how-do-i-skip-the-first-key-on-a-zip-that-compares-2-hashes

Answer (score 1):

Edit: better, I think:

```
hash1.all? { |k,v| !(v.empty? ^ (hash2[k]==[""])) }
  #=> false
```

Original answer:

```
keys = hash1.keys
  #=> ["1", "2", "3", "4"] 
hash1.values_at(*keys).zip(hash2.values_at(*keys)).all? do |v1,v2|
  !(v1.empty? ^ (v2==[""]))
end
  #=> false
```

`^` is Ruby's XOR operator.

Comment: Cary is probably assuming that the order in the hashes are not guaranteed. If they are, it can become `hash1.values.zip(hash2.values) ...`.

Comment: I don't think your `v2.empty?` part is correct. It's more than that.

Comment: Should not `v2.empty?` be `!v2.all?(&:empty?)`?

Comment: @sawa, yes, I used `values_at` because I was making no assumption about the order of keys.

Comment: You can also go with `hash1.sort.values.zip(hash2.sort.values) ...`.

Comment: @mudasobwa, perhaps I misinterpreted the question I thought `true` was to be returned if, for every pairing, both were empty or neither were empty, or, equivalently, it is not the case that exactly one of each pair is empty (XOR).

Comment: @sawa Generally speaking, if the order is not guaranteed, then probably we should handle not matched keys as well.

Comment: `v2` is _an array_ there. And `XOR` will return `true` when one operand is true, while other is false.

Comment: @mudasobwa, yes, I know `v2` is an array and `v1` is a string, but they both have `empty?` methods. And yes, If one is `true` and the other `false`, XOR returns `true`, but I then negate that. No?

Comment: @sawa, yes on `sort`, but I assume `values_at` is faster.

Comment: As by OP: `"4"=>[""]` and `[""].empty? == false`, while it should be considered to be `true`.

Comment: @mudasobwa, ah, I finally get it! I was thinking `[]` rather than `[""]`. Will fix.

Comment: Your first one passes `"1"=>"val"` and `"1"=>[""]` when it would fail

Comment: user3234020, thanks. I should have noticed that. I forgot the parentheses around `hash2[k]==[""]` and, in my original answer, around `v2==[""]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
hash1.merge(hash2){|_, v1, v2| v2.dup.push(v1)}
.all?{|_, v| v.all?(&:empty?) or v.none?(&:empty?)}
```

Or following @mudasobwa's suggestion:

```
hash2.merge(hash1){|_, v2, *v1| v1 + v2}
.all?{|_, v| v.all?(&:empty?) or v.none?(&:empty?)}
```

Comment: `hash2.merge(hash1){|_, v2, *v1| v2 + v1}...` ⇒ no `dup` and imho more readable.

Comment: @mudasobwa Maybe that is better. I just wanted to make use of the fact that `v1` is a string and `v2` is an array.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: `v.all?(&:empty?) or v.none?(&:empty?)` ⇒ `%i|all? none?|.any? { |m| v.public_send(m, &:empty?) }` :)

Comment: @sawa how would this fit into an if else scenario or statement. I want to say if its false do something.

Comment: @sawa nearly what I need. but if if an array contains `["", "value"]` its classed as empty

Comment: @user3234020 Your question is absolutely unclear about such case.

Comment: @sawa Sorry that is what I was trying to get across with 'has one value in the array and that value is blank' incase there was another value in the array after the first blank one. (I'm not the best at explaining things)

Comment: @user3234020 according to your definition *"have a value [...] means there must be a non-blank value in the array"* and `["", "value"]` does have a non-blank value. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
def compare_hashes(hash1, hash2)
  (1..hash1.length).each do |n|
    n = n.to_s # can easily swap this if you want to use integers or symbols
    return false if hash1[n].empty? || hash2[n].empty? || hash2[n].all?(&:empty?)
  end

  true
end
```

Comment: `nil?` should be `empty?` according to the OP. BTW, this approach is way too phpish.

Comment: indeed thanks. How is it specifically phpish? I would say it's not particularly rubyish.

Comment: Well, iterators should not care on enumerable’s length, return from the middle of the function is ugly (use `break false` instead,) especial dedicated method is redundant etc.

Answer (score 0):

The following is more-or-less a direct translation of the requirements.(*)

```
# similar(h1,h2) assumes that h1 is a string-valued hash,
# and that h2 is a hash with values that are all arrays of strings.
#
def similar(h1,h2)
  return false if h1.length != h2.length
  h1.all? {|key, v1|
    v2=h2[key]
    v2 != nil and 
      ((v1=="" and v2==[""]) or
       (v1 != "" and !v2.all?{|x| x.length==0} ))
  }
end
```

(*) The OP stipulated that the two hashes have the same number of keys, so the check that that's the case could perhaps be omitted, but there is no harm in checking, and the method as written is likely to be a tiny bit more useful (or at least more realistic) with the check included. Feel free to omit it.

Comment: `return false if h1.length != h2.length` is unnecessary. That is mentioned in the question.