# How do I skip the first pair in `zip`?

Tags: ruby, iterator

The following code compares two hashes: one with strings as values and the other with arrays as values.

```
hash1 = {"1"=>"val", "2"=>"val", "3"=>"vall", "4"=>""} 
hash2 = {"1"=>[""], "2"=>["value"], "3"=>["val1", "val2"], "4"=>[""]} 

unless hash1.zip(hash2).all? { |(_, fv), (_, lv)|  fv.empty? ^ !lv.all?(&:empty?) }
  ...
end
```

If `hash1` has an empty string and `hash2` has a value or vise versa, it is false.

I need the comparison to skip the first element in both hashes. I would add `with_index` to do so, but I don't know how to add it or if it's the best way in this case.

Comment: maybe ` hash1.zip(hash2).slice(1..-1)` ?

Comment: You could use [Enumerable#each_with_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index):  `hash1.zip(hash2).each_with_index.all? { |((_, fv), (_, lv)),i| i.zero? || fv.empty? ^ !lv.all?(&:empty?) } #=> true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `zip` is an array, so just cut off the head:

```
hash1.zip(hash2).drop(1).all? { ... }
```

You can't use `with_index` since `any?`, unlike `map` and others, does not return an `Enumerator`. You could do a workaround:

```
hash1.zip(hash2).map.with_index { |((_, fv), (_, lv)), i|
  i.zero? || fv.empty? ^ !lv.all?(&:empty?)
}.all?
```

But that's like the very opposite of legible.

EDIT: Thanks to sawa for improving (and debugging) the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
keys = hash1.keys.drop(1)
  #=> ["2", "3", "4"] 
pairs = hash1.values_at(*keys).zip(hash2.values_at(*keys))
  #=> [["val", ["value"]], ["vall", ["val1", "val2"]], ["", [""]]] 
pairs.all? { |v1,v2| v1.empty? ^ v2.uniq != [""] }
  #=> true
```

You could of course chain the last two expressions.